# repeat steps in specflow

Tags: cucumber, bdd, specflow

I'm having long Scenario with Specflow and I need to add 3 users, all the steps are the same. How can I repeat just couples of steps in the flow?

## Scenario Outline: Register with Multiple users

```
Given Go to page
#Login
And Click on sign in button
When Enter email 'mail@gmail.com'
And Enter password '123456' 
And Click on Submit button
And click on Events list button
And Open Event  
And Go to new opened page       
And  Click on Register to event button
```

## These steps I need to repeat

```
When Click on Person title '<title>'    
And Select ticket package
And Select ticket quantity '15'
And Click on submit registration button 
And Enter mail <email> to register to event
And Enter first name <first name> to register to event
And Enter last name <last name> to register to event
And Click on submit registration button
And Click on submit registration button 
Examples: 
| title    | email          | first name | last name |
| Person 1 | mail1@mail.com | Person1    | Person1   |
| Person 2 | mail2@mail.com | Person2    | Person2   |
| Person 3 | mail3@mail.com | Person3    | Person3   |
```

## Stop repeating and finish scenario

When click on Continue button
Then 3 user should be in the list

Comment: Not entirely sure what you need to do, using scenario outline will repeat all of the steps you said you want to repeat. The example you gave, does that not work for you?

I would say it looks like you have way to many steps for a single scenario, you are actually able to execute other steps from within a single step if you inherit the "steps" class on your own feature steps class

Comment: the thing is that I'm receiving 3 different tests as the result of this code while I need only 1 test, and not to rewrite same steps, I need to repeat just i piece in the long flow.

Comment: In one execution I need to create 3 users. and it would be easy if user creation would be 1 step, but there are 5 steps to create 1 user, than I need again repeat these 5 steps, and again. And than continue execution in normal way.

Comment: Oh OK I'll write an answer that might help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what I did and seems working fine for me

When Register multiple users '3' to event click on 'Person'

```
[When(@"Register multiple users '(.*)' to event click on '(.*)'")]
        public void WhenRegisterMultipleUsersToEventClickOn(int userQty, string title)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= userQty; i++)
            {
                WhenClickOnPersonTitle(title + " " + i);
                WhenSelectTicketPackage();
                WhenSelectTicketQuantity(10);
                WhenClickOnSubmitRegistrationButton();
                WhenEnterMailToRegisterToEvent("mail" + i + "@mai.com");
                WhenEnterFirstNameToRegisterToEvent("Name" + i);
                WhenEnterLastNameToRegisterToEvent("Lastname" + i);
                WhenClickOnSubmitRegistrationButton();
                WhenClickOnSubmitRegistrationButton();             
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call steps from within another step. Within your steps class inherit the TechTalk.SpecFlow.Steps class like so;

```
public sealed class RegisterMultipleUsersSteps : Steps
{
  ...
}
```

Ok so why is this helpful? well you can now call the 5 steps to create a single user into one step so do something like below

```
Scenario Outline: Register With Multiple Users
 Given Go to page
 ...
 When i create user 'Person1' 'Last name 1' with email 'mail1@mail.com'
 When i create user 'Person2' 'Last name 2' with email 'mail2@mail.com'
 When i create user 'Person3' 'Last name 1' with email 'mail3@mail.com'
 ...
 Then Some condition
```

I'll assume you already have the steps to create the user with the individual credentials already created since you listed them in your question.

In you steps class for this feature, where you previously inherited the spec flow steps class do something like the following

```
[When(@"I create user (.*) (.*) with email (.*)")]
public void WhenICreateUserTitleNameSurnameWithEmailAddress(var firstName, var lastName, var emailAdd)
{
  // Now because you inherited the specflow steps class 
  // you can call other steps that you already have      
  When(string.Format("Enter mail {0} to register to event", emailAdd));
  When(string.Format("Enter first name {0} to register to event", firstName));
  When(string.Format("last name {0} to register to event", lastName));
  When("Click on submit registration button");
}
```

This allows you to more easily create a user without cluttering your scenarios too much. You could probably merge some more of your steps as well.

A side note, i think the generally accepted standard for writing in gerkhin language is to keep features as simple as possible normally no more than 5 steps, this is documented somewhere on specflows website and loads of other places. The idea being that if you need more than that you should split up your tests or some functionality can be merged.

I hope the above helps.

Comment: I would never choose to call a step from another step, even if it possible. What I would do is to extract the desired functionality into a common helper and use that helper instead. Calling steps from steps will lead you down a path of a tangled mess and personally, I would avoid it at any cost.

Comment: @ThomasSundberg Fair enough, i find it works well for us, we have most of our functionality in helper functions but we want to reduce repeated code by calling the same functions in the same order in multiple steps but only have 1 minor change, we find the embedded step approach works well for us. I think the downvote is a little unfair since the above is a legit solution

Comment: thanks guys for answers. And what about @tags, maybe it is possible to reuse scenarios by calling @tag? Cannot find clear explanations how tags can help me not to dublicate scenarios